# Excel 2010 using Querytables and a few other things

Tags: excel, vba

I am handling a few Excel things professionally and are running into issues. I am forced to use web queries to pull an exportable Excel files with parameters defined in the excel document. For reasons we are not able to use power query and I have to drudge up my old programming knowledge and put something together. This is not anything critical, just improving our work environment.

I have nailed down most of the process but have to condense everything or else I will reach the maximum size limit very quickly running it sequentially.

The sections I am working with will be set in rows of 4 and as many columns as needed until there are no more. I am planning on basing the criteria in the code on the first cell of section 1 because there will be a value in this cell if there is more. The cells do need to be formatted as text due to the web connection URL but this has not caused any issues.

[image: Input Format]

The code I have is more individual instruction for excel then any kind of VBA logic but it has worked for the bit I have tested. The issue I have is condensing it down to loop through the sections in the "Input" sheet. I apologize for any sloppy declarations or names as I am going to clean it up to add error messages and comments once I have something that is functional. (I have left out the url information since it is internal.)

```
Sub myworkbook()

Dim wsi As Worksheet

Dim sourl, sosd, sosd2, soed, soed2, sodm, soaf, soev, soexc, soflag, sobn As String
Dim sa, sb, sc, ea, eb, ec, dm, af, ev, exc, flag, bn As String
Set wsi = Sheets("Input")

sourl = "URL1"
sosd = "URL2"
sosd2 = "URL3"
soed = "URL4"
soed2 = "URL5"
sodm = "URL6"
soaf = "URL7"
soev = "URL8"
soexc = "URL9"
soflag = "URL10"
sobn = "URL11"

sa = wsi.Range("A2").Value
sb = wsi.Range("B2").Value
sc = wsi.Range("C2").Value
ea = wsi.Range("A4").Value
eb = wsi.Range("B4").Value
ec = wsi.Range("C4").Value
dm = wsi.Range("F2").Value
af = wsi.Range("I2").Value
ev = wsi.Range("L2").Value

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

flag = wsi.Range("A11").Value
bn = wsi.Range("A14").Value


With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.add(Connection:="URL;" & _
sourl & sosd & sa & sosd2 & sb & sosd2 & sc & soed & _
ea & soed2 & eb & soed2 & ec & sodm & dm & soaf & af & _
soev & ev & soexc & exc & soflag & flag & sobn & bn, _
Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").Delete
```

The issue I am having at the moment is I want to take 1 cell from section 1 and 1 cell from section 2, update the querytable and output the exported to a separate sheet then move on to the second cell in section 2 with the same cell in section 1. We do not have any issues with the formatting with the output as we use it to put together reports manually but it would help if I could use a variable for the destination in the query table to add a column but I have been unable to figure out how to use a range variable for the destination so far.

Using the example image the flow needs to be;

Start at A1
Use value of A1 and A7
Update querytable, output to another sheet
Use value of A1 and B7
Update querytable, output to same sheet with one column of space
etc...

Move to next section using values G1 and G7 when section 1 is done
Update querytable, output to separate sheet
etc..

I have been unable to figure out how to do this and do not have any code examples as nothing has been functional enough to use as a start. I have been playing around with using the name as a starting point and creating a new sheet based on the name to output the information to and having the macro delete all of the sheets before running a new set when the macro is executed. If this is something that can be done I would love to do this as it would make it more automated and need less input and just require the users to keep to the format in the document if new sections are added.

The main issues I have been having is the sparse amount of information on using query tables for web connections due to power query's implementation and my knowledge of Visual Basic has diminished to a point that I feel like a baby learning to walk.